# avoiding warnings in Perl when using try-catch using Try::Tiny and Module::Runtime

Tags: perl, module, runtime, try-catch

I have this code currently in a part of my perl script (working fine) :

```
try {
        no strict 'refs';
        require_module $modules{$action_name};
        if ( &{"FFTG::${actiontype}::run"}( $action, $fs, $log ) ) {
                $log->res("SUCCESS");
        } else {
                if ( $action->{mandatory}[0] == 1 ) {
                        $log->res("FAIL, exiting.");
                        last ACTION;
                } else {
                        $log->res("FAIL, but not mandatory, continuing..");
                }
        }
}
catch {
        $log->res("MODULE NOT FOUND");
        print "no module found for action '$actiontype', unable to process this action\n";
        #warn $_;
};
```

but unfortunately, the output of the script shows these 3 errors in the middle of the output (all lines beginning with **Exiting subroutine**):

```
starting transfer ..
no module found for action 'Transfer', unable to process this action
no module found for action 'Transfer', unable to process this action
no module found for action 'Archive', unable to process this action
Exiting subroutine via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.
Exiting eval via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.
Exiting subroutine via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.
ending transfer
```

even if the script works perfectly, I find it "dirty" to display these errors on the standard output.

is there a way to get rid of them ?
(I cannot use if/then etc.. because I don't want the script to exit with this require_module thing).
I just want my script to display an alert if it cannot find a module (it does), but not these warnings

thanks again
regards

Comment: Are you sure they are not from code you wrote, or that is in your own code base?

Comment: https://grep.metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=via+last&qd=&qft=

Comment: I think they are from something. But I don't fully understand this yet.

Comment: sorry simbabque the code is quite long now and I didn't paste everything on purpose, but I had a label called ACTION: on top of a higher loop (not shown here), thanks btw, it's solved with tjd's solution, even if it's not a good idea to hide warnings, I can hide "just the warning I want" :)

Comment: Oh I see it now. Sorry. The call to last is in the block for try, which is not a block but an anonymous sub. That's why it complains. You need to set a variable that's scoped outside the try and use it to trigger last below the try.

Comment: I get it, thanks for the information, I will try that !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [`perldoc perldiag`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Exiting-eval-via-%s) we find that those warnings are in a group named "exiting".

If you used `no warnings "exiting";` just prior to line 130 in fftgv2.pl, you would silence the warnings for the remainder of that block.

... of course paying attention to the warnings wouldn't be the worst idea either.

Answer (score 4):

The warnings are issued because you've got a `last` inside the block of a `try` statement. The `try` is not actually part of the Perl syntax. It's not a keyword, and as such, the block is not really a block. It's just an anonymous sub that's treated like a block because of the prototype `sub try (&;@)` in Try::Tiny.

We're going to look at it from the bottom up.

> ```
> Exiting subroutine via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130. ^
> Exiting eval via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.       |
> Exiting subroutine via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130. |
> ```
>
> Exiting subroutine via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.

So the third warning is actually from the sub for your `try`.

```
try {                      # here
        no strict 'refs';
```

> Exiting eval via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.

The next one is because Try::Tiny [implements `try` via a call to `eval`](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.28/lib/Try/Tiny.pm#L94), [Perl's built-in way of catching errors](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

This is the code Try::Tiny uses (highlighted comment mine):

> ```
>   # failed will be true if the eval dies, because 1 will not be returned
>   # from the eval body
>   my $failed = not eval {              # here is 2)
>     $@ = $prev_error;
>  
>     # evaluate the try block in the correct context
>     if ( $wantarray ) {
>       @ret = $try->();                 # and this is 3)
>     } elsif ( defined $wantarray ) {
>       $ret[0] = $try->();
>     } else {
>       $try->();
>     };
>  
>     return 1; # properly set $failed to false
>   };
> ```

> Exiting subroutine via last at ./bin/fftgv2.pl line 130.

And the first warning is from the actual `sub try` in Try::Tiny itself.

---

So what can you do about it? If you don't want to just hide the warnings, you need to rewrite your code a little. Get rid of the `last` inside of the `try` block, and instead either make it exit via a `die`, or simply `return`. Remember, it's a function after all.

Then set a value that you use later to decide if you want to skip the iteration or not.

```
ACTION: foreach my $action_name (@foo) {
    my $break_out;
    try {
        no strict 'refs';
        require_module $modules{$action_name};
        if ( &{"FFTG::${actiontype}::run"}( $action, $fs, $log ) ) {
            $log->res("SUCCESS");
        }
        else {
            if ( $action->{mandatory}[0] == 1 ) {
                $log->res("FAIL, exiting.");
                return $break_out = 1; # use this to exit the loop later
            }
            else {
                $log->res("FAIL, but not mandatory, continuing..");
            }
            # return is only needed if there is more code here ...
        }
        # ... or here
    }
    catch {
        $log->res("MODULE NOT FOUND");
        print "no module found for action '$actiontype', unable to process this action\n";
    };

    last ACTION if $break_out; # oops, something went wrong, break out
}
```